# Returning the ID of the component which is in viewport

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web, antd

I want to return the value of the component currently in viewport. 
To do this, I referd some documents, and thought I could make it by using *Ant Design*.

The function I refered to *Ant Design* is *Anchor*. I want to get *key* value of `Anchor` tag. 
There is a [document](https://ant.design/components/anchor) explaining usage of it, but don't know how to use it to get value of current component.

I made three components in my codes. And want to show their number at the top. 
Can I know how to make it?

Sorry for difficult question to understand but I'm sure you could understand better if you see my code or CodeSandBox below. Thanks

**code :**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Anchor } from "antd";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  //tried to use these, but failed
  const [currentView, setCurrentView] = useState();
  console.log(currentView);
  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {});

  return (
    <Wrap>
      <Anchor
        targetOffset={currentView}
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        items={[
          {
            key: "part-1",
            href: "#part-1",
            title: "Part 1"
          },
          {
            key: "part-2",
            href: "#part-2",
            title: "Part 2"
          },
          {
            key: "part-3",
            href: "#part-3",
            title: "Part 3"
          }
        ]}
      />
      <div className="fixed">currentcomponent : {currentView}</div>
      <div>{currentView}</div>
      <div id="part-1" className="compo1">
        components 1
      </div>
      <div id="part-2" className="compo2">
        components 2
      </div>
      <div id="part-3" className="compo3">
        components 3
      </div>
    </Wrap>
  );
}

const Wrap = styled.div`
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  .fixed {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }

  .compo1 {
    border: 3px solid red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 70vh;
  }

  .compo2 {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 70vh;
  }

  .compo3 {
    border: 3px solid green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 70vh;
  }
`;
```

**CodeSandBox:**
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-architecture-sgeikl?file=/src/App.js:0-1694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), to observe the component in the viewport, you can add the observer in the `useEffect` hook without dependences to only run on the component initial load.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Anchor } from "antd";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [currentView, setCurrentView] = useState();
  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {});

  useEffect(() => {
    const components = document.querySelectorAll(".comp");
    const componentObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function (
      entries,
      observer
    ) {
      entries.forEach(function (entry) {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          setCurrentView(entry.target.id);
        }
      });
    });
    components.forEach((comp) => {
      componentObserver.observe(comp);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Wrap>
      <Anchor
        targetOffset={currentView}
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        items={[
          {
            key: "part-1",
            href: "#part-1",
            title: "Part 1"
          },
          {
            key: "part-2",
            href: "#part-2",
            title: "Part 2"
          },
          {
            key: "part-3",
            href: "#part-3",
            title: "Part 3"
          }
        ]}
      />
      <div className="fixed">currentcomponent : {currentView}</div>
      <div>{currentView}</div>
      <div id="part-1" className="compo1 comp">
        components 1
      </div>
      <div id="part-2" className="compo2 comp">
        components 2
      </div>
      <div id="part-3" className="compo3 comp">
        components 3
      </div>
    </Wrap>
  );
}

const Wrap = styled.div`
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  .fixed {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }

  .compo1 {
    border: 3px solid red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .compo2 {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .compo3 {
    border: 3px solid green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
`;
```

[image: Edit festive-varahamihira-ziemf5]